# What is the difference between en.activerecord.erros and en.errors.messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are similar definitions in en.yml and I don't know how to use them differently.

```
[lang]:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
  errors:
    messages:
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is preceendence. Given:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

The I18n module will try the following keys in this order and return the first result:

```
activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.blank
activerecord.errors.models.user.blank
activerecord.errors.messages.blank
errors.attributes.name.blank
errors.messages.blank
```

It will thus check for more specific error messages first.

See Rails Guides: [Error Message Scopes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes).